# How to add new values to every element in large Laravel Collection but bulk operation

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I'm optimizing some legacy code on Laravel 5.1 version, there is a process where I have a large Laravel collection and I need to add 3 new values to every element inside the collection, this 3 new values will be the same for all the collection elements.

Currently this is achieved iterating over every element and adding the values, I was wondering if there is something like a bulk operation to avoid iterating over every element because doing this in a large collection is very time consuming.

The code is currently is doing this, converting to array and then merging the 3 new values to every collection element:

```
$extraValues = [
    'value1' => 'value1',
    'value2' => 'value2',
    'value3' => 'value3'
];

$rows = array_map(function ($row) use ($extraValues) {
            return array_merge($row, $extraValues);
         }, $lotesChunk);
```

Comment: Laravel 6 onward there is Lazy Collection, that would have helped here. All the best. You will have to implement [PHP Generators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) yourself it seems.

Comment: If you are referring by `Collection` to SQL Data, I would go straight to SQL commands and sidestep any type of ORM (build-in or otherwise)

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I think avoiding the ORM and trying to add the values from SQL query could be a good approach. Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: If this is a one time thing then just go to SQL commands. If you are going to have to do this repeatedly, you may want to look into Queues and Job batching.